# Set property values within linq expressions

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Having

```
Dim hiddens As List(Of Integer))
```

I want to do set Hidden properties of UltraGridRows using this list values as indexes:

```
hiddens.Select(Function(x) ultraGrid1.Rows(x).Hidden = True)
```

That line compiles and i get not runtime exception at all, but corrsponding rows are not hidden. Is this a valid way to set properties in expressions?

Comment: Don't _set_ properties with LINQ. Use loops if you want to modify something. Use LIN(Q) if you want to query something.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, i dont see why i should not. Any comment on this?

Comment: Because LINQ should not have side-effects. [Erip Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx): "The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect."

Comment: You aren't supposed to modify things even inside a `foreach` statement. LINQ is a *query* language. It's optimized to query things and is perfectly justified in assuming that there will be no side effects no matter how a query is executed. That's what allows it to work with multiple providers or concurrently.

Comment: Besides, the `Select` statement compares `Hidden` with `True`, it doesn't change the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *set* properties with LINQ. Use loops if you want to modify something. Use LIN(Q) if you want to query something. So you could simply use a `For Each`(which i would use):

```
For Each index As Int32 In hiddens
    ultraGrid1.Rows(index).Hidden = True
Next
```

or use `List.ForEach`:

```
hiddens.ForEach(Function(index) ultraGrid1.Rows(index).Hidden = True)
```

[Erip Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx): "The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect. The purpose of a statement is to cause a side effect."

Note that your query does not even execute until you use a`For Eeach`(or other method that does it implicitly like `ToList`). It's just the definition of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hiddens.ForEach(Function(x) ultraGrid1.Rows(x).Hidden = True)
```

Comment: Do you really  recommend creating a new list just to be able to set a property?